# Can a tax debt owed to an EU country cause me any trouble in another EU country?

Tags: european-union, debt

I have recently left my country (Greece) and moved to Germany. While I am employed and everything functions perfectly, I have some debts to Greece's tax collection bureau.

While I will be able to pay those debts in a couple of years, in the meantime, is this any cause for concern about my situation on Germany? Can this affect me in any way?

Comment: You might consider asking this at [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The European Enforcement Order is an explicit procedure for uncontested claims like this. That means no German court is involved (unlike Dale M's answer suggests). The Greek Court files an EEO, and this can be enforced directly in Germany without going through German courts again. That means you can face wage garrisons, bank account freezes etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

If the Greek tax agency successfully sues you for the debt in a Greek court, a German court will enforce the judgement. This is not just an EU thing - in most countries domestic courts will enforce foreign judgements that comply with local law.